# Strange Error Trying to Install Certain Packages in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the dplyr package in R.

When I do it I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Matt/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages     
InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
      unable to access index for repository       https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
```

I am able to install some packages and not others where I get this error.  I have changed the mirror.  Also I have uninstalled R and R studio and reinstalled.  No luck.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Please check if any of these will help http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+InternetOpenUrl+failed

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer - but it isn't what I'd consider "good".  I just kept trying to load the package and finally it worked.  I know that my connection was good which suggests to me it was a problem at the CRAN mirror.  However, that doesn't make complete sense because I manually changed mirrors and had the same problem.  So unless the mirrors are somehow really tied together in real time I'm not sure how that could be the problem.  So - my "not good" advice is to just keep trying to load the package over an extended period of time and it (hopefully) should work.